# How to avoid snails/slugs on pet's food outside?

Tags: health, diet, outdoor, pest-control

My two rabbits get some additional tasty food when I close their enclosure at night. This helps me to train them "Coming home is tasty" and they will come in without pressure.

But the last days were very rainy, and now there are within 30 minutes snails/slugs at the food.

How can I save the food from being eaten by snails/slugs?

(My rabbits avoid the parts slimy from them, like I would do too without the reach of water to clean them...)

[image: slugs inside the food bowl of my rabbits]

Answer (score 2):

You can build a barrier with salt.

Your fresh food lies on a plate. Put a second plate that's bigger than the first underneath. The second plate should be so big that there is at least two fingers width of space all around (so the snails must walk through the second plate and cannot climb from the rim directly into the first plate). Then put a thin line of common table salt into the second plate, all around the rim.

Snails hate salt and are not able to cross it. You must make sure that the food lies neatly in the first plate and doesn't form a bridge for the snails, like the leaf of the corn cob does in your picture. This also avoids contaminating the food with salt.

Comment: Do you know, if rabbits are smart enough to avoid the salt too? :) I will try it. The taste of pure salt should "scare" the rabbits of eating it "raw". But I will check, if the rabbits pull the food out of the plate and touch the salt with it...

Comment: The plate in your picture has a high rim. If the second plate also has a high rim, the food shouldn't touch the salt, even if it's dragged from the plate. Maybe a carrot could fall into the gap and become contaminated with salt, though.